# Json parsing very slow in android

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, android-asynctask

In my app i am trying to fetching favorite music,movies,books of friends from facebook.
Here i did so far.

1. I am requesting facebook for favorites and getting the response as json.
2. now i want to parse this in background.

my problem is parsing is executing very slow.I am iterating using for loop.It takes 8 to 10 seconds for whole parsing.so is there any way to do it little faster.

```
public ArrayList<String> parsing()
{
       long time1=System.currentTimeMillis();
      // System.out.println(time1);
       ArrayList<String> urls=new ArrayList<String>();


       int position=0;
    try {       
     String response=Utility.responseSecond;
    JSONObject node1=new JSONObject(response);              
    JSONArray array1=node1.getJSONArray("data");
    int length=array1.length();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(array1.getJSONObject(i).getString("id").equals(friendId.toString()))
        {
            position=i;
        }
    }
       JSONObject node2 = array1.getJSONObject(position);

          try{

              if(node2.has("music"))
              {

         JSONArray array2=node2.getJSONObject("music").getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject node4=array2.getJSONObject(0);

                    String name=node4.getString("name");

                    JSONObject node5=node4.getJSONObject("picture");
                    JSONObject node6=node5.getJSONObject("data");
                    String musicsurl=node6.getString("url");




                    urls.add(musicsurl);

              }


                }
          catch(JSONException e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

          try{


              if(node2.has("movies"))
              {

                  JSONArray array2=node2.getJSONObject("movies").getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject node4=array2.getJSONObject(0);
                    String name=node4.getString("name");

                    JSONObject node5=node4.getJSONObject("picture");
                    JSONObject node6=node5.getJSONObject("data");
                    String moviesurl=node6.getString("url");
                    urls.add(moviesurl);

              }

              }
              catch(JSONException e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

          try{

              if(node2.has("books"))
              {
              JSONArray array2=node2.getJSONObject("books").getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject node4=array2.getJSONObject(0);
                String name=node4.getString("name");

                JSONObject node5=node4.getJSONObject("picture");
                JSONObject node6=node5.getJSONObject("data");
                String bookurl=node6.getString("url");
                urls.add(bookurl);


              }
          }
              catch(JSONException e)
              {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

          try{
              if(node2.has("television"))
              {
              JSONArray array2=node2.getJSONObject("television").getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject node4=array2.getJSONObject(0);
                String name=node4.getString("name");

                JSONObject node5=node4.getJSONObject("picture");
                JSONObject node6=node5.getJSONObject("data");
                String televisionsurl=node6.getString("url");

                urls.add(televisionsurl);

              }
          }
              catch(JSONException e)
              {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("JSONException", e.getMessage());


            }
    System.out.println("in parsing"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time1));

    return urls;


   }
```

Comment: have u used Asyctask?

Comment: yes i am using asynctask.

Comment: i am calling this method from doin background and updating in onpostExecute method.

Comment: i think ur data is huge if possible use pagination on server side itself

Comment: instead of parsing json responses yourself, take some time to learn jackson json parser http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome. i have used it many times and its very fast and very simple to use. also very powerful (and clever)

Comment: thank u very much.i ll read and try it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this by youself, check this pls:
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It is easy to use and it is also fast.

Comment: Thanx.I think gson is used to convert java objects to json.Here i want opposite.Can u plz help me for that @JaredLuo

Comment: Gson can do them both...like this: Person person = gson.fromJson(str, Person.class);